# Get the people who approved the release in the logs

Tags: azure-devops

Good morning, I need to get the people who approved the release in the logs, in the option to download all logs the approval of the release is not found, it is only shown in the vsts interface. For audit it is necessary to have it in a .log, I have seen that it can be done with a task by calling an api but the method is by oauth2, I need to see how I can have that information and step by step how it would be done. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use REST API in the task of pipeline, in fact, there has another easily method offered by Azure Devops which equals with `Oauth 2.0`: [Stystem.AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken).

This is a predefined variable which carry the security token and used during the running build. Use this variable in pipeline, you will not need `Oauth 2.0` any more. For how to use this is **System.AccessToken**, just add it in the Headers of API called script:

```
$headers = @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
```

**Note:** To use this variable, you must enable `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token` in the agent job first.

---

In the doc of REST API, we offer one api which can [get a list of approvals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/approvals/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/approvals?api-version=5.1
```

But there has disadvantage on this api, it just can get the list of approvals which is **pending** approval. This means, once the approve finished(approve/deny), you will not get it any more with using this api.

As what you say, you should want the approvers displayed in log, so I recommend you use the follow [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/Releases/Get%20Release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=5.1
```

It can display all of approvers including in pre-deploy, post-deploy.

```
$headers = @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
$uri = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/release/releases/$(release.releaseId)?api-version=5.1"
$result =Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $headers 
Write-Host "Pipeline = $($result| ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

In this script, `release Id` is set as be achieved automatically from predefined variable, so you don't need specified it firstly in the script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to hear, you can accept my answer:-)